# Map static field from different table in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Our application is using a table to store application wide settings in a property table like this (using JPA):

```
public class Property {
    String key; // primary key
    String value;
}
```

One of our entities needs to have one of those properties, a base directory for file storage, (same one for ALL entities of this type) in a static field (it doesn't need to be static, but it would make sense).

```
public class FileEntity {
     public static String BASE_DIR;
     ...
}
```

There is no mapped relationship between those to entites yet and there is nothign to be used as a foreign key from any side.
Is it possible anyway, to define a mapping which inserts the *value* of the *Property* with *key="basedir"* into the *BASE_DIR* attribute of the *FileEntity*?

*BASE_DIR* not being static would be kind of ok, but the content would still be the same for all instances of *FileEntity*.

Comment: `BASE_DIR` is the wrong spelling for a non-constant variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly not as elegant as you would have wished:

```
@Entity
public class FileEntity {

    private static String BASE_DIR;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
```

Have a property service with a @PostConstruct to initialise all your entities

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    FileEntity.setBaseDir(propertyRepository.findByKey("key1").getValue());
}
```

After all the beans have been loaded the static fields on your entities will be set and belong to the class.

Comment: Correct, not es elegant as I hoped, but nevertheless the most elegant solution so far. We made it a little more ugly by moving the BaseDir into an Interface (thx Java8!), but that works nicly for us.